# Anaconda Installation for windows doesn't work

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

After I install the anaconda package for windows, **there is no scripts folder inside the installation folder**(C:\Users\user\Anaconda3):

These are the only files inside:

[image: Anaconda Fonder]

I try to run the installation as **admin**, but the problem remains.

After the installation, there are no trace of:

- Environment variables for conda;
- Conda executable
- Anaconda Prompt

Comment: Looks like a failed install.  If you can run it as Admin, try installing to C:\Anaconda3

Comment: I tried it, but the same happens. It seems only a few itens are created, but the installation is finished successfully.